# F# - Recursion with anonymous records

Tags: recursion, f#

Given the following F# snippet:

```
type A(children: A list) = 
    member val P1 = ""
    member val P2 = ""
    member val Children = children

type B = {
    F1:string
    Children: B list
}

let rec f1 (a:A) = 
    {
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map f1
    }

let rec f2 (a:A) = 
    {|
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map f2 //Error
    |}

let a = A([A([A([])])])

f1 a
f2 a

////////////////////
Error   FS0001  Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'A -> 'a'    
but given a
    'A -> {| Children: 'a list; F1: string |}'    
The types ''a' and '{| Children: 'a list; F1: string |}' cannot be unified.Active
```

The compiler complains in f2 but not in f1.

**What would be the correct syntax for anonymous record (if it exists)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be a correct syntax, this is just impossible.

Think about what would be the return type of `f2`. Since it's a record with a field `Children` that is a list of the same record, it would look something like this:

```
{|
  F1: string
  Children: list<
    {|
      F1: string
      Children: list<
        {|
          F1: string
          Children: list<
            ...
          >
        |}
      >
    |}
  >
|}
```

It's an infinite type. Such a beast doesn't exist.

**Q:** but Fyodor, obviously the element of the `Children` list is the exact same record, can't it just be that?

Well, no, there is no way to say "the exact same record", because it doesn't have a name. The compiler would be like "*what record? exact same as what?*"

When you declare a named record, on the other hand, you can use the very same record as element of the list, because now the record itself is a "thing". It has its own identity, which is separate from its content, so it can be referenced separately from it.

I think the error message could be clearer though.

Comment: well, I think its a bit misleading to say there is no type that satisfies this? there is a recursive type that does satisfy this, but because its anonymous, you havent got the syntax to write it

Comment: Not in the F# type system

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to make an anonymous record that's recursive. The problem is that the compiler can't infer the return type of `f2`, and hence can't infer the type of the anonymous record's `Children` field. As humans, we can see that making the type recursive would solve the problem, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fyodor's answer and I think it may be interesting to dig a bit deeper.

so lets make it a bit more explicit

here is the code that you wrote that works

```
type B = {
    F1:string
    Children: B list
}

let rec f1 (a:A) : B = 
    {
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map f1
    }
```

you then try to use an anonymous record to construct the equivalent issue, but lets do it explicitly and tell the compiler the type we expect using type aliases and see where it fails

```
type C = {| F1: string; Children: C list |} //Error is here

let rec f2 (a:A) : C = 
    {|
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map f2 
    |}
```

so the error here is on the type alias

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0953  This type definition involves an immediate cyclic reference through an abbreviation F# Miscellaneous Files
```

this type isnt allowed for the reason Fyodor explained, effectively the compiler would try to evaluate this type alias by replacing the inner C with the type alias definition and clearly this would never terminate.
(this scenario is quite common in other, but not all, languages).
This problem isn't just isolated to anonymous records, but any recursive type alias e.g.

```
type Foo = Foo -> Foo
```

The normal route out is to give the type an explicit name so usually wrapping the inner expression in a data constructor (note this is now no longer a type alias).

```
type C = C of {| F1: string; Children: C list |}

let rec f2 (a:A) : C = 
    {|
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map f2
    |}
    |> C
```

and this type is basically equivalent to the explicitly named type B.

Brian's assertion that there may not be a way to make an anonymous type recursive though isnt quite correct, we can do this as long as there is some named type in the recursive definition e.g.

```
type C<'a> = {| F1: string; Children: 'a list |}

type D = D of C<D>

let rec f2 (a:A) : C<D> = 
    {|
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map (f2 >> D)
    |}
```

our f2 function is now defined in terms of a recursive anonymous record, but we've had to inject a named type into the recursion (and thus we have to use the data constructor D in our f2 function), the issue though IS that there is no anonymous (finite) type that satisfies your original function definition, not that there is, but the compiler can't find it.

---

it seems to be unclear as to the status of C

if we type this

```
let x : C<D> = {| F1=""; Children=[] |}

x.GetType();;
```

into FSI it replied

```
val it: System.Type =
  <>f__AnonymousType3901454931`2[Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[FSI_0002+D],System.String]....
```

i.e. C is an anonymous type of type {| F1: string; Children: D list |}

we can, of course, completely dispense with this alias e.g.

```
type D = D of {| F1: string; Children: D list |}

let rec f2 (a:A) : {| F1: string; Children: D list |} = 
    {|
        F1 = a.P1
        Children = a.Children |> List.map (f2 >> D)
    |}

let x = f2 <| A([A([A([])])])
```

Comment: You don't have an anonymous recursive type in your last example. The anonymous type `C<'a>` isn't technically recursive, because it doesn't mention itself, while the recursive type `D` is not anonymous. What you've done is basically type `B` with more steps: the nominal constructor is separate from the rest of the type.

Comment: C<D> is anonymous and recursive

Comment: you can see its anonymous because the value is constructed using anonymous type syntax {|...|} and is clearly recursive

Comment: `D` is not anonymous.

Comment: f2 doesnt return D, it returns C<D>. String is also not anonymous, so i don't see the relevance. C<D> is anonymous and recursive and the return type of f2...and almost the same function definition the OP wrote. So Im hoping it may be of some interest to him.

Comment: Don't you see the point? You're solving the recursion problem the exact same way as in `B` - by inserting a data constructor between recursive iterations. So it's nothing new compared to `B`.

Comment: Sorry I dont. B isnt anonymous, C<D> is. The question is about anonymous recursive types, so if i stop at B, I havent really answered the question.

Comment: the question was "What would be the correct syntax for anonymous record (if it exists)?" you've explained why there isnt one given the OPs definition of the f2, I've simply shown there is one with a small alteration.

Comment: I'm with Fyodor. `C<D>` obviously isn't anonymous, because it has a name: `C<D>`.

Comment: FSI says it is anonymous. It's constructed with the anonymous record syntax. Just because its anonymous doesnt mean that it can't refer to named types, else it wouldn't be very useful

Comment: I've even declared it now explicitly as anonymous